# Dagger 2 error injecting dependencies in android

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm learning DI with Dagger 2 but I have some problems with dependency injection, I'm using MVP for this app so I have separated by package all my classes.

I'm trying to inject a dependency to my presenter but I'm getting this error "cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.", I have checked my code and I have checked some examples and I assume that I'm injecting this dependency, I've tried in different ways and I can't fix this error and I don't know how to fix it.

Only I want to open a second activity calling from SplashActivity the presenter, but injecting this through DI.

**Library in Gradle**

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.17'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.17'
```

**MovieApplication.java**

```
    public class MovieApplication extends Application {

    private AppComponent appComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        setupGraph();
    }

    private void setupGraph() {
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .build();
    }

    public static MovieApplication get(Context context){
        return (MovieApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    public AppComponent getAppComponent() {
        return appComponent;
    }
}
```

**AppComponent.java**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {

    @ApplicationContext
    Context context();

}
```

**AppModule.java**

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    private MovieApplication mMovieApplication;

    public AppModule(MovieApplication movieApplication) {
        this.mMovieApplication = movieApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    @ApplicationContext
    Context provideContext(){
        return mMovieApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    Application provideApplication(){
        return mMovieApplication;
    }
}
```

**MovieComponent.java**

```
@MovieScreenScope
@Component(dependencies = AppComponent.class, modules = MovieModule.class)
public interface MovieComponent {

    void inject(SplashActivity splashActivity);
}
```

**MovieModule.java**

```
@Module
public class MovieModule {

    private Activity mActivity;

    public MovieModule(Activity activity) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Provides
    @ActivityContext
    Context provideContext(){
        return mActivity;
    }

    @Provides
    Activity provideActivity(){
        return mActivity;
    }

    @Provides
    @MovieScreenScope
    SplashPresenter<SplashView> provideSplashPresenter(SplashPresenterImpl<SplashView> presenter){
        return presenter;
    }

}
```

**SplashActivity.java**

```
public class SplashActivity extends BaseActivity implements SplashView {

    @Inject
    SplashPresenter<SplashView> presenter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getMovieComponent().inject(this);
        presenter.openLoginActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void openLoginActivity() {
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
        finish();

    }

    @Override
    public void openHomeActivity() {
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, ContainerActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

**BaseActivity.java**

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MovieComponent movieComponent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setupGraph();
    }

    private void setupGraph() {
        movieComponent = DaggerMovieComponent.builder()
                .movieModule(new MovieModule(this))
                .appComponent(MovieApplication.get(this).getAppComponent())
                .build();
    }

    public MovieComponent getMovieComponent() {
        return movieComponent;
    }
}
```

**SplashView.java**

```
public interface SplashView {

    void openLoginActivity();
    void openHomeActivity();
}
```

**SplashPresenter.java**

```
public class SplashPresenterImpl<V extends SplashView> implements SplashPresenter<V> {

    private SplashView splashView;

    @Inject
    public SplashPresenterImpl(V splashView) {
        this.splashView = splashView;
    }

    @Override
    public void openLoginActivity() {
        splashView.openLoginActivity();

    }

    @Override
    public void openMainActivity() {

    }

    @Override
    public void verifyInternetConection() {

    }

    @Override
    public void getMoviesData() {

    }

}
```

**SplashPresenter.java**

```
@MovieScreenScope
public interface SplashPresenter <V extends SplashView> {

    void openLoginActivity();
    void openMainActivity();
    void verifyInternetConection();
    void getMoviesData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem here seems is with the `splashView` parameter in the constructor of `SplashPresenterImpl` class. When the object of `SplashPresenterImpl` is created by dagger, it tries to find the `@Provides` method that returns the `SplashView`. Basically it is trying to find the `SplashView` in the dependency graph and as there exists no method annotated with `@Provides` that is returning this object, it gives this error.